# How I can use CSS in my Div Area for the ListView Hover Effect

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview, hover

I use a jquery dialog and i want use CSS for the div area. I use a ListView with LinkButtons and I want a hover effect I try it with this but it don't work.

**aspx: (div area)**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Liste">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imageSearch" runat="server" 
                ImageUrl="~/Theme/Pictures/lupe.jpg" Height="24px" Width="25px" 
                onclick="imageSearch_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Zu Vertreter hinzufügen" 
                onclick="btnEdit_Click" Width="246px"/>                
                <hr />                 
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">                           
                          <LayoutTemplate>
                                 <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr style="background-color:#ccdaeb" class="TableClass">
                                            <th align="left" id="th4" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNachname" runat="server" CssClass="MyLink">Name</asp:LinkButton> </th>
                                            <th align="left" id="th6" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAbteilung" CssClass="MyLink" runat="server">Abteilung</asp:LinkButton></th>    
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder"></tr> 
                                 </table>    
                         </LayoutTemplate>

                         <ItemTemplate>       
                                      <tr class="TableClass"> 
                                          <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="lblDisplayName" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                                          <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="abteilung" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="lblAbteilung" Text='<%# Eval("Abteilung") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                                      </tr>            
                         </ItemTemplate>

                         <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                           <div><h4>Es wurden keine Einträge gefunden</h4></div>
                         </EmptyDataTemplate>

                         <AlternatingItemTemplate>                
                                      <tr class="TableClass"> 
                                          <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="lblDisplayName" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayName") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                                          <td align="left"><asp:LinkButton  CssClass="MyLink"  CommandName="abteilung" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' ID="lblAbteilung" Text='<%# Eval("Abteilung") %>' runat="server"  /></td>
                                      </tr>            
                         </AlternatingItemTemplate>    
            </asp:ListView>

</div>
```

**My CSS file:**

```
#UserTable
{
    background-color:#ccdaeb;        
}

.MyLink 
{
    color:Black;
    text-decoration:none; 
}   

.MyLink:hover
{
    text-decoration:underline; 
} 

#TableClass
{
    background-color:#ccdaeb;
}  

.TableClass:hover
{
    background-color:#E5EDF5;
}
```

What I make wrong

Comment: do you have a link? it could be that you have other css rules that override this. a peek at the markup and ALL the css available to the page would help.

Comment: CSS is used to style HTML, not ASP; please dear C# developers, would you mind to post HTML when asking CSS related questions? Because this question has nothing to do with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#TableClass` - it looks like mistake and should be `.TableClass`. Also `.TableClass` is applied to tr. Not sure why, but I've noticed that background-color does not work with TRs.

try change your css to

```
.TableClass td
{
    background-color:#ccdaeb;
}  

.TableClass:hover td
{
    background-color:#E5EDF5;
}
```

Also, I see this code:`id="UserTable" runat="server"`

Because of runat=server id of that table will be changed, so css below will not work

```
#UserTable
{
    background-color:#ccdaeb;        
}
```

You may solve it like this:
`<table id="UserTable" runat="server" class="UserTable" ...`
and css:

```
 .UserTable
    {
        background-color:#ccdaeb;        
    }
```